# Taking not specified attribute,

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have problem because i have one div from left of the right div, with registration fields. Problem is that sometimes someone could provide not proper values to registration form and then `<form>` and containing it `rightDiv` getting bigger `height` but this height is not specified explicitly. How can i change, in this case, height of leftDiv to height of rightDiv, after height of rightDiv was changed?
example html:

> ```
> <div id="leftDiv" style="float: left">
>     <p>Hello</p>
> </div>
> <div id="rightDiv">
>     Here are registration related inputs fields.
> </div>
> ```
>
> Registration is not via ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a wrapper and `display:inline-block`. This should work:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div style="display: inline-block; width:50%">
  <p>Hello</p>
 </div>
 <div style="display: inline-block; width:50%">
  Here are registration related inputs fields.
 </div>
<div>
```